# Amalgamated Free Product Calculation in van Kampen Theorem

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $U_1, U_2$ be the open cover of space $X$. Then by van Kampen theorem, the fundamental group of a torus $\mathbb{T}$ can be simplified to $(\mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z}) *_{\mathbb{Z}} \{e\}$. I think the free product of $(\mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z}) * \{e\}$ is just $\mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z}$, but how to make the amalgamation? Wikipedia says there's two maps from the underline group (here is $\mathbb{Z}$) to $U_1$ and $U_2$, but how to choose it?

Reference: https://mediaspace.illinois.edu/media/1_3w5n3nln at around 42:00.

Comment: You are misusing the notion of an amalgamated free product $A*_C B$:  There one requires $C$ to inject in both $A$ and $B$, which is not the case in the general van Kampen's theorem and in the torus example. The question is essentially a duplicate of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20043/seifert-van-kampen-and-free-product-with-amalgamation?rq=1).

Comment: You need to get a picture in your head so you can interpret the theorem.

Comment: The two maps from $\mathbb{Z}$ are mentioned in the video. The map from $\mathbb{Z} \to \{e\}$ is the obvious one, and then the map from $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z}$ is $1 \mapsto b^{-1}a^{-1}ba$

Comment: So the pushout group as mentioned as $\mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z} * e$ modulo $b^{-1}a^{-1}ba = e$ i.e. $(\mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z}) / (b^{-1}a^{-1}ba)  $ which is exactly modding out by the commutator so you get $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fundamental group of torus by van Kampens theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/827411/fundamental-group-of-torus-by-van-kampens-theorem)